# O365: Deleting messages via POP3 suddenly not working

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, pop3

A third-party app is using POP3 to download messages from a O365 mailbox. This has been working great for a few months. Some time on Saturday, `DELE` commands just stopped working. Looking through the logs of the protocol chatter - it seems like it *should* be working.

```
# connect okay via oauth
==> LIST
<== +OK 1 262599\r\n2 34077\r\n3 58453\r\n4 64196\r\n5 62522\r\n6 59719\r\n.\r\n
==> CAPA
<== +OK UIDL\r\nSASL PLAIN XOAUTH2\r\nUSER\r\nCLIENTACCESSRULES\r\nCLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION\r\nBACKENDAUTHENTICATE\r\nSERVERAUTH\r\n.\r\n
==> UIDL 1
<== +OK 1 5705056
==> DELE 1
<== +OK
==> UIDL 2
<== +OK 2 5705059
==> DELE 2
<== +OK
...
==> QUIT
<== +OK Microsoft Exchange Server POP3 server signing off.
```

Upon re-connect, the messages are still there. Deleting messages via EWS works; deleting from the web email client works.

We tried using a different mailbox and that works fine, too. So it's as if there's a POP3 specific problem on one specific account.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you checked the audit logs if there where any changes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/audit-log-search-script

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you provided, it is possible that the issue is related to the basic auth deprecation coming in October.
The service has been temporarily disabling basic auth so that tenant admins become aware they are using it. If you log into the M365 portal with your tenant admin account, you will likely find messages in the message center about this 1. Outlook Desktop does not support POP or IMAP in the service with modern auth, so those won’t work after October. The best thing to do is to switch your account to an Exchange connection.

Comment: But the server is connecting over OAuth, not basic auth. I've not heard anything about POP3/IMAP protocols being deprecated?